# Странное поведение "потока" после textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

Есть такая разметка:

```
   <div id="postAddingTab">
            <div id="postContainer">
                <div id="post">
                    <div id="postDescWrapper">
                        <textarea id="postDesc">

                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="postWrapper">
                        <textarea id="post">

                        </textarea>

                    </div>
                    <div id="postButtons">
                        <button>Сохранить</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="postOptions">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

В результате кнопка прилипает вправо к нижней textarea, несмотря на то, что она в своем div'e. Вот [тут](http://ozka.github.io/blogv3/adminpanel.html) можно увидеть что происходит. (Надо ткнуть сверху на "вкладку" создать). Если я комментирую обе textarea и пишу, например, вместо них просто текст, то все ок, кнопка размещается как бы ниже блоков, обрамляющих textarea.

На всякий случай вот код [css](https://github.com/OZKA/ozka.github.io/blob/master/blogv3/adminstyle.css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#postWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: Спасибо! Увы, плюсануть не хватает рейтинга...